# Unable to download some packages on Redhat

Tags: rhel, yum, repository

I am unable to download the pam-devel, zlib-devel and openssl-devel packages on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo).

When executing

```
yum install pam-devel
```

I am getting the following error:

```
error: No package pam-devel available.

error: Nothing to do
```

While running

```
yum repolist all
```

the following content is being displayed:
[image: Output]

I am not able to enable the repositories running

```
yum-config-manager --enable epel-source/x86_64.
```

[image: Output]

Why are the packages not available and what I can do to get them?

Answer (score 6):

EPEL is an add-on repository. The pam-devel, zlib-devel and openssl-devel packages would all be part of the main RHEL distribution, and so EPEL would have no reason to include them.

In the beginning of your `yum repolist all` output, there is this message:

```
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
```

Accessing the main RHEL repositories on the internet requires registering the system with RedHat and paying for support subscription. Once the system is registered, a plugin included in RHEL's `yum` will automatically give you access to the RHEL repositories.

Comment: I agree with this answer, I just wanted to add:  you said you’re running 7.4. Expect to get a *lot* of updates to your system once you’ve registered a subscription. You are extremely out of date. If you’ve never updated since the initial 7.4 install, you are missing many security updates as well.